# Getting rid of a specific windows update on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update, automatic-updates

I've just moved from Windows Server 2003 to 2008, and I'm having a very annoying experience with Automatic Updates.

In Windows 2003, when it "suggested" a package and I chose not to install, it asked whether I was sure and it never suggested it again.
In Windows 2008, when I uncheck it it lets me continue, but it keeps insisting that I install it, which is pretty annoying.

Is there a way to choose not to install specific fixes?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right-click the update and select Hide Update

Comment: Hmmmm, I feel dumb right now... I HAD tried to double click them and nothing seemed to happen :-(  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: no worries... it's not exactly that obvious :)